# How do I use two-finger zoom in Appium / webdriver-io

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm new to mobile automation, but not new to automation in general (worked with web). I'm building an automation where a two-finger zoom is required. I've looked through documentation trying to find a solution, and can't find one. There is Multi-Touch, but it's a misnomer because it seems to implement many different touches with one finger only in quick succession. Something like this doesn't appear to work:

```
client.touchMultiPerform([
  [{ action: 'press', options: { x: 300, y: 100 } },
   { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
   { action: 'release' },
  ],
  [{ action: 'press', options: { x: 330, y: 100 } },
   { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 400, y: 100 } },
   { action: 'release' },
  ],
]);
```

This does the first touch action, then the second touch action. Is there a method that allows this? Maybe a plugin? Or am I just not understanding a remarkably simple solution?

Here's a more complete example of what I've built:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var config = require('./helpers/desiredCapabilities').options;
var client = webdriverio.remote(config);


describe('Android Script Testing', function () {

 before(function () {
     this.timeout(5000);
     return client.init();
 });

 afterEach(function(){
     this.timeout(5000);
 });

 it("should just click on things",async function(){
     this.timeout(0);
     client.click("#selectRegionButton")

     client.waitForVisible("#Account", 5000).click("#Account");

     client.touchAction(
         [
           [{ action: 'press', options: { x: 300, y: 100 } },
           { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
           { action: 'release' }],
           [{ action: 'press', options: { x: 330, y: 100 } },
           { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 400, y: 100 } },
           { action: 'release' }],
         ]);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are using Appium here, but if there is Appium in use then zoom and pinch will only work with `Espresso` Automation name in the desired capabilities.

Same is confirmed [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9491#issuecomment-416164210) and I have also tested the same using `Espresso` Automation name in Appium Java binding.

Try using the same automation name and your code should work.

Also, you have used `client.touchAction` in your code, instead use `client.touchMultiPerform`.

Comment: Thank you. I believe you are correct. I am using Appium, so I'll check out `Espresso` and see what I come up with.

Comment: Make sure you are running on a non-windows environment as Espresso Automation name in Appium will error out on Windows machine.